# Vault (HashiCorp) - curl equivalent of "vault read"

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Small question regarding Hashicorp Vault please.

I have a secret in Vault, under `cubbyhole/mytestkey`

If I log in to the web UI, I can see the key `mytestkey` and its value under `cubbyhole`

If I use the Vault CLI, running `vault read /cubbyhole/mytestkey`, I do get the result.

```
vault read /cubbyhole/mytestkey
Key     Value
---     -----
mytestkey    mytestvalue
```

However, when I use via curl (The token should be correct, since I used it to connect to Vault web UI), I get:

```
curl -vik -H "X-Vault-Token: token" https://remote-vault/cubbyhole/mytestkey
HTTP 404
```

May I ask what is the issue with my curl command? A path issue? And the correct one would be?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your REST API endpoint is missing the port and the version of the API. You can update it to:

```
curl -vik -H "X-Vault-Token: token" https://remote-vault:8200/v1/cubbyhole/mytestkey
```

and modify the port if running on the non-default `8200`.

You can find more information in the [relevant documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/cubbyhole#read-secret).

Comment: How can we get path exactly ? I have secrets/Proj/Cred inside which I have creds. It is working in local but in live throws error

Answer (score 2):

Spend hours trying to figure out how to get the correct URL.

My key/values are stored in `kv / myapp / database`

```
Key         value 
server      10.10.10.1
```

To get the CURL url use `-output-curl-string` flag.

```
vault kv get -output-curl-string -mount=kv -field=server myapp/database
```

Result

```
curl -H "X-Vault-Request: true" -H "X-Vault-Token: $(vault print token)" http://vaultserver.dev:8200/v1/kv/data/myapp/database
```

source: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/kv-secrets-engine-via-curl/30629